# Run command on OpenWRT router via webpage

Tags: command-line, bash, router, php, openwrt

I've developed a static webpage hosted via an OpenWRT firmware based router and would like to create a reset button held on that page, the console command is:

```
reboot
```

I'm struggling to work out the logic to do this. I have permissions to allow for it however. Could anyone offer advice or any articles around this subject? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make webpages using html, but you can't include command in it. So you have to make **sh** file and you can write html code in it. The reset command is

```
jffs2reset -y && reboot
```

Here, I made file for you when you click to Reset it will resets router.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""
echo '<html>'
echo '<head>'
echo '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">'
echo '</head>'
echo '<body style="background-color:#10abe1">'
echo "<form method=GET action=\"${SCRIPT}\">"
echo '<center><br><input id ="button" type="submit" value="Reset">'\
echo '</form>'
# If no search arguments, exit gracefully now.
if [ -z "$QUERY_STRING" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    jffs2reset -y && reboot
fi

echo '</body>'
echo '</html>'
exit 0
```

I think this will help you.

Comment: If above code work perfect, then give it as right answer. So anyone can prefer this. Thank You